# What tool can test my server for slowloris attacks?

Tags: security

What is a good tool that will help me find out if my server is being attacked by slowloris?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method is to use `netstat` to check the number of open connections:

```
$ netstat -nt
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          127.0.0.1:39521         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          127.0.0.1:39906         ESTABLISHED
…
```

If that list ever gets huge, you're likely being hit by slowloris:

```
…
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address         Foreign Address       State      
tcp      232      0 67.230.168.1:80       96.125.213.1:56837    ESTABLISHED
tcp      232      0 67.230.168.1:80       96.125.213.1:56831    ESTABLISHED
tcp      232      0 67.230.168.1:80       96.125.213.1:56752    ESTABLISHED
… many more …
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out using `netstat`.
But if you want to protect yourself from Slowloris you can use `mod_antiloris` module which can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-antiloris/).

It is really simple to install.

```
cd /usr/local/src

wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-antiloris/files/mod_antiloris-0.4.tar.bz2

tar -xvjf mod_antiloris-0.4.tar.bz2

cd mod_antiloris-*

apxs -a -i -c mod_antiloris.c
```

If you are using Apache 2.4

```
apxs2 -a -i -c mod_antiloris.c
```